# Sinatra + Rspec2 - Use Sessions/Helpers?

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, rspec2

I am trying to test my Sinatra app using Rspec2 but I can't get access to sessions or helper methods in my tests.

**spec_helper:**

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../myapp.rb"
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'rack/test'
require 'rspec'
require 'factory_girl'

set :environment, :test

RSpec.configure do |conf|
  conf.include Rack::Test::Methods
end

def app
  Sinatra::Application
end
```

**app_spec.rb:**

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../spec_helper.rb"

describe 'Something' do

  it "should do something" do
    session["aa"] = "Test" 
  end

end
```

**This throws an error, can't find session variables. Similarly I can't use helper methods which are defined in my app.**

I run my tests using `rspec specs/app_spec/app_spec.rb`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've got your specs and spec helper in the /spec dir, then this line should go at the top of your spec:

```
require_relative "./spec_helper.rb"
```

I also like to use File.expand_path and File.join as it's more reliable than doing it yourself, e.g.

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../spec_helper.rb"
```

becomes

```
require_relative File.expand_path( File.join File.dirname(__FILE__), "/../spec_helper.rb" )
```

Also, I don't tend to `require "sinatra"`, the app has that. If you're missing bits from sinatra then maybe, but I add things like this instead through rack:

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'
```

Finally, if your Sinatra app is using the modular style then you'll have to include it too. I do this at the top of a spec, for example:

```
describe "The site" do
  include Rack::Test::Methods
  include MyApp
  let(:app) { MyApp.app  }
```

YMMV. Let us know if any of this works.

---

A different test to try:

```
before(:all) { get "/" }
subject { last_response }
it { should be_ok }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The spec_helper.rb file is included correctly (I can access other things defined in it), that's not the problem. I'm not using the modular style. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'd try moving the `include Rack::Test::Methods` and app declaration into the spec and seeing if that works. You might try a different kind of test first, to make sure it works instead of going for the session stuff, see my edit.

Comment: btw, just realised (face palm!) using Rack::Test is really for integration tests, so you won't be accessing helpers or sessions directly anyway. Read this post on testing helpers http://japhr.blogspot.com/2009/03/sinatra-innards-deletgator.html

Comment: Thank, I tried that before but it didn't help with using session variables.

Comment: Oh yeah, the basic tests (like the one you posted) work fine, I jsut can't access session[..]

Comment: why do you want to access session directly?